# Getting error while run the dspmqver command

Tags: ibm-server

We have installed Websphere MQClient version is v9.0.0.1 on linux machine.but while installing MQClient rpm packages,we are getting below error.

please check and help on this issue adn i could see the `libmqmcs_r.so` file is available in path `/infaicc/app/MQClient/lib`,so i have set the environment variable with below command.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/infaicc/app/MQClient/lib64`,but still getting same error.

Note: It is multi-installtion setup, already websphere MQC version 8.0.0.4 has been installed in different location `/Informatica/app/MQClient`,but its working fine.

```
rpm -ivh --prefix /infaicc/app/MQClient MQSeriesRuntime-9.0.0-1.x86_64

/infaicc/app/MQClient/bin/amqiclen: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[root@XXXX-as-0037 bin]# ./dspmqver
./dspmqver: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[root@XXXX-as-0037 bin]#
```